# ElasticSearch query to return document with this format of text

Tags: elasticsearch

We have been experimenting with our ElasticSearch instance to build a query which will find a document that has text in unstructured formats.  This particular document is giving us a very difficult time.

This is the contents of a field in the document called "`Text`."

```
PUBLIC NOTICE – September 2013 NORTH DAKOTA BOARD OF NURSING 919 S 7th Street, Suite 504, Bismarck, ND 58504-5881; (701) 328-9777; Web Site www.ndbon.org PLEASE SHARE THIS INFORMATION WITH YOUR NURSING STAFF The North Dakota Board of Nursing took the following action during the September 19, 2013 meeting: Disciplinary/Board Action Action Name Registration # City/State Time frame Penalty fee Reprimand *Anderson, Merry 106815UAP Minot, ND N/A $200 * Practice without *Buboltz, Ann RN Applicant Redwood Falls, MN N/A $200 License/ Dockter, Amanda L13872 Kensal, ND N/A $900 Registration Jaffe, James R39137 Elkhart, IN N/A $600 *Miller, Cassandra RN Applicant Wahpeton, ND N/A $1,000 *Parker-Sundquist, Charla LPN Applicant Grand Forks, ND N/A $200 Extension of Cofer, Kelly R32728 & L11293 Grand Forks, ND 3 years $1,500 Previous Wattendorf.
```

Please note toward the end of the text block, the phrase "Parker-Sundquist, Charla."

We need this document returned in the results set when any variation of the name Charla Parker-Sundquist is searched.  Right now, we are able to return the document if we search on Charla Parker-Sunquist, or if we search on Parker-Sundquist, Charla.  However, we tried searching on Charla R Parker-Sundquist (including middle initial) and the document is not returned.

We need to tweak this query (or build an additional one) that will allow for slight variations like adding a middle initial, and still return that document, **but**, *without* the query saying that all documents with at least one of the search terms should be returned.  What I *believe* we would need to do with this query is say that we want to return any results that have at least two of the search terms present and within two words proximity of each other.

Here is the query as we have it now.  With this, the document in question will be returned when searching on the two variations mentioned above.  But as soon as we introduce a middle initial into the query, the document is not returned.  Please help me understand how we can tweak this query without saying that **ANY** of the 3 words can be in the document for it to be returned.

```
   {
        "size": 150,
        "query": {
            "function_score": {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": {
                            "bool": {
                                "should": [
                                    {
                                        "match_phrase": {
                                            "text": {
                                                "query": "charla r parker-sundquist",
                                                "slop": 3
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

**EDIT**: per some research, we also tried this query, but this one doesn't bring back ANY results at all, so I'm not sure if the syntax is way off on this one.

```
{
    "size": 150,
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "bool": {
                            "should": [
                                {
                                    "span_near": {
                                        "clauses": [
                                            {
                                                "span_multi": {
                                                    "match": {
                                                        "fuzzy": {
                                                            "text": {
                                                                "value": "charla",
                                                                "fuzziness": 2
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "span_multi": {
                                                    "match": {
                                                        "fuzzy": {
                                                            "text": {
                                                                "value": "parker-sundquist",
                                                                "fuzziness": 2
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "in_order": false,
                                        "slop": 2
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get full search customization you can change the indexing tokenizer and and use a custom analyser.: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html

Then you have more search options, and you can also use the query_string query. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html

Some examples:
[Multiple tokenizers inside one Custom Analyser in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549567/multiple-tokenizers-inside-one-custom-analyser-in-elasticsearch)

Comment: Thanks but I guess I should mention that re-creating our index with a new tokenizer isn't really an option.  We have a total of 5 queries that run on our index (including the one outlined above) and the other 4 queries are working very well as designed.  Re-building our index with a new schema could very well jeopardize what we have working well.

Comment: In that case, you need to understand the current tokenisation in order to decide how to query, if possible, depending on how it is tokenized. Use the analyse API to check it: GET index-name/_analyze
{
  "text" : "put your text here"
}

Comment: Thanks for that tip.  The result of the analyze query can be seen here: http://tinypic.com/r/ve3bqd/9  Can you help me understand what this means?  Thank you.

Comment: Just FYI, I added a 2nd query in the post that we tried based on some research.  This one didn't work either.