# Elasticsearch: custom tokenizer split by words and dots

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize

I'm trying to create a tokenizer that will work this way:

```
POST dev_threats/_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
  "text": "some.test.domain.com"
}
```

and get tokens like:

```
[some, some.test, some.test.domain, some.test.domain.com, test, test.domain, test.domain.com, domain, domain.com]
```

I tried ngram tokenizer:

```
    "ngram_domain_tokenizer": {
      "type": "ngram",
      "min_gram": 1,
      "max_gram": 63,
      "token_chars": [
        "letter",
        "digit",
        "punctuation"
      ]
    },
```

But for long values, it generates too many tokens...

Any idea how to get such result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need two different analyzers for this. There's another solution using shingles and it goes this way:

First you need to create an index with the proper analyzer, which I called `domain_shingler`:

```
PUT dev_threats
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "domain_shingler": {
          "type": "custom",
          "tokenizer": "dot_tokenizer",
          "filter": [
            "shingles",
            "joiner"
          ]
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "dot_tokenizer": {
          "type": "char_group",
          "tokenize_on_chars": [
            "punctuation"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "shingles": {
          "type": "shingle",
          "min_shingle_size": 2,
          "max_shingle_size": 4,
          "output_unigrams": true
        },
        "joiner": {
          "type": "pattern_replace",
          "pattern": """\s""",
          "replacement": "."
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "domain": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "domain_shingler",
        "search_analyzer": "standard"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you try to analyze `some.test.domain.com` with that analyzer, you'll get the following tokens:

```
POST dev_threats/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "domain_shingler",
  "text": "some.test.domain.com"
}
```

Results:

```
{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "some",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "some.test",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "shingle",
      "position" : 0,
      "positionLength" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "some.test.domain",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 16,
      "type" : "shingle",
      "position" : 0,
      "positionLength" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "some.test.domain.com",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 20,
      "type" : "shingle",
      "position" : 0,
      "positionLength" : 4
    },
    {
      "token" : "test",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 1
    },
    {
      "token" : "test.domain",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 16,
      "type" : "shingle",
      "position" : 1,
      "positionLength" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "test.domain.com",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 20,
      "type" : "shingle",
      "position" : 1,
      "positionLength" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "domain",
      "start_offset" : 10,
      "end_offset" : 16,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "domain.com",
      "start_offset" : 10,
      "end_offset" : 20,
      "type" : "shingle",
      "position" : 2,
      "positionLength" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "com",
      "start_offset" : 17,
      "end_offset" : 20,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 3
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [path hierarchy tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer.html#analysis-pathhierarchy-tokenizer)

```
PUT my-index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "custom_path_tree": {
          "tokenizer": "custom_hierarchy"
        },
        "custom_path_tree_reversed": {
          "tokenizer": "custom_hierarchy_reversed"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "custom_hierarchy": {
          "type": "path_hierarchy",
          "delimiter": "."
        },
        "custom_hierarchy_reversed": {
          "type": "path_hierarchy",
          "delimiter": ".",
          "reverse": "true"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST my-index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "custom_path_tree",
  "text": "some.test.domain.com"
}

POST my-index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "custom_path_tree_reversed",
  "text": "some.test.domain.com"
}
```

** Result**

```
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "some",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "some.test",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 9,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "some.test.domain",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 16,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "some.test.domain.com",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 20,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}


{
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "some.test.domain.com",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 20,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "test.domain.com",
      "start_offset" : 5,
      "end_offset" : 20,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "domain.com",
      "start_offset" : 10,
      "end_offset" : 20,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "com",
      "start_offset" : 17,
      "end_offset" : 20,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}
```

It will create path like tokens by splitting on given delimiter. Using  normal and reverse option you can get tokens in both directions

Comment: Looks good, but in fact, I'd like to have it in one single tokenizer that does the standard and reversed job...

Comment: I could make a 2 separate analyzers and then use them both in a search query like here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52549567/multiple-tokenizers-inside-one-custom-analyser-in-elasticsearch